# SizeLimitExceededException vs FileSizeLimitExceededException - Different exception for different file sizes

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, multipart, upload-max-filesize

We are getting different exceptions when we upload files of different sizes. The max file size allowed is **1 MB**.

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=1MB
```

When we try to upload a file of **5.95 MB** we get `FileSizeLimitExceededException` and when we try to upload a file of **21.5 MB** we get `SizeLimitExceededException`. Why are two different exceptions thrown for two different file sizes, even when both violate the pre-defined file size?

This is our custom exception handler

```
@Slf4j
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(2)
public class CommonErrorHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler({ SizeLimitExceededException.class })
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public ResponseEntity<CommonResponse> fileSizeException(SizeLimitExceededException ex) {

        CommonResponse response = new CommonResponse(String.valueOf(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value()), "File upload size exceeded SizeLimitExceededException!");

        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    
    @ExceptionHandler({ FileSizeLimitExceededException.class })
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public ResponseEntity<CommonResponse> fileSizeException(FileSizeLimitExceededException ex) {

        CommonResponse response = new CommonResponse(String.valueOf(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value()), "File upload size exceeded FileSizeLimitExceededException!");

        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

Due to this, we have to maintain two different methods in our exception handler. Later, we had to use the superclass of both these exceptions `SizeException` to handle it in one method.So,

1. Why we were getting different exceptions for different file sizes?
2. Will the usage of `SizeException` be a good way to handle it?